# Boost Beast HTTP

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, boost, boost-beast

I am working on a http parser, and it looks like boost.beast is a nice one. However, I still have some questions:

*** Assume HTTP Request POST data already received via boost.asio socket. Stored inside a std::string buffer.

1. Is there any good sample on how to extract http header fields and its value (one-after-another)? I assume it will be an iterator method, but i tried several way and still won't work.
2. How to extract the http body?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from a simple example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/client/sync/http_client_sync.cpp

```
    // Declare a container to hold the response
    http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

    // Receive the HTTP response
    http::read(socket, buffer, res);
```

### Extract The Headers

The response object already contains all the goods:

```
for(auto const& field : res)
    std::cout << field.name() << " = " << field.value() << "\n";

std::cout << "Server: " << res[http::field::server] << "\n";
```

You can also just stream the entire response object:

```
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

### Extract The Body

```
std::cout << "Body size is " << res.body().size() << "\n";
```

To actually use the "dynamic_body", use standard Asio buffer manipulation:

```
#include <boost/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp>

std::string body { boost::asio::buffers_begin(res.body().data()),
                   boost::asio::buffers_end(res.body().data()) };

std::cout << "Body: " << std::quoted(body) << "\n";
```

> Alternatively, see [`beast::buffers_to_string`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__buffers_to_string.html)

Obviously, things become more straight-forward when using a `string_body`:

```
std::cout << "Body: " << std::quoted(res.body()) << "\n";
```

Comment: I didn't know about `std::quoted`! An alternative for output is `std::ostream&` using `std::cout << beast::buffers(res.body().data()) << "\n";`. The function `beast::buffers` adapts a buffer sequence into something that works with `operator<<`.

Comment: @VinnieFalco Learning everyday here. I really like that you comment these things. Cheers!

Comment: Print just the headers: `std::cout << res.base();`

Comment: @VinnieFalco +1 In this case we were trying to specifically cater to the question "how to extract http header fields and its value (one-after-another)? "

Comment: Maybe `basic_fields::value_type` should have an `operator<<`. I'll open an issue. See: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1143

Comment: @VinnieFalco std::cout << res.base(); is not working in boost 1.70.0 version. I tried with beast::make_printable(res.base()), this is also not working. Please let me know your input

Comment: It works fine, there's even a test for it:
https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/41040a21f0b0e12537beb1262c2d538a023efe65/test/beast/http/write.cpp#L612

Does this test compile for you?

Comment: @VinnieFalco Thanks. I am still having some issue. Can you please advice, if I am doing something wrong?

using BeastResponse = http::response<http::string_body>;
...
BeastResponse mResponse;
...
std::stringstream lHeaderStream;
lHeaderStream << mResponse.base();

Error:
/mnt/src/mobi-med-boost/cmake/../src/boost/beast/core/ostream.hpp:81:5: error: static assertion failed: The function buffers() is deprecated, use make_printable() instead, or define BOOST_BEAST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED to silence this error.
     static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0,

Comment: ‘void boost::beast::buffers(const T&) [with T = boost::beast::detail::buffers_ref<boost::beast::buffers_cat_view<boost::asio::const_buffer, boost::asio::const_buffer, boost::asio::const_buffer, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >::writer::field_range, boost::beast::http::chunk_crlf> >]’:
src/boost/beast/http/impl/write.hpp:906:25:   required from ‘std::ostream& boost::beast::http::operator<<(std::ostream&, const boost::beast::http::header<true, Fields>&) [with Fields = boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'

Comment: @VinnieFalco can you please help with code snippet? I am learning and unable to fix

Comment: @user2260304 [1.69.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O1zzfWMdVQUMEQN7), the error message with [1.70.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lC0j8jp9xTcXkubk), the workaround with [BOOST_BEAST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ezLIEIjKrwePLOk8)

Comment: @VinnieFalco AFAICT the fix using `make_printable` should replace `buffers` in e.g. [L:906/916 (....?) of the library write.hpp implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/include/boost/beast/http/impl/write.hpp). That compiles as well

Comment: Thanks @sehe for the help